# dependency issues why I try to run/debug my app

Tags: flutter, dart, dependencies, pubspec.yaml

I'm new to making an app with flutter/dart and I'm running into some issues with the dependecies in the pubspec.yaml. I'm trying to make an app from a template to learn about how to work with repositories from github. After I brought in the code and repaired all the errors I tried to run/debug it and keep getting this from the output terminal:

> Because google_sign_in >=5.4.0 depends on google_sign_in_platform_interface ^2.2.0 which depends on quiver ^3.0.0, google_sign_in >=5.4.0 requires quiver ^3.0.0.
> And because cloud_firestore >=0.14.0-dev.1 <0.17.0-1.0.nullsafety.0 depends on quiver ^2.0.0, google_sign_in >=5.4.0 is incompatible with cloud_firestore >=0.14.0-dev.1 <0.17.0-1.0.nullsafety.0.
> Because cloud_firestore >=0.13.3 <0.14.0-dev.1 depends on firebase_core ^0.4.4 and cloud_firestore >=0.11.0 <0.13.3 depends on firebase_core ^0.4.0, cloud_firestore >=0.11.0 <0.14.0-dev.1 requires firebase_core ^0.4.0.
> Thus, if google_sign_in >=5.4.0 and cloud_firestore >=0.11.0 <0.17.0-1.0.nullsafety.0 then firebase_core ^0.4.0.
> And because txapita depends on cloud_firestore >=0.11.0 <0.14.0+1, google_sign_in >=5.4.0 requires firebase_core ^0.4.0.
> So, because txapita depends on both firebase_core ^2.4.1 and google_sign_in ^5.4.2, version solving failed.
> pub get failed (1; So, because txapita depends on both firebase_core ^2.4.1 and google_sign_in ^5.4.2, version solving failed.)
> exit code 1

Also, how do I get rid of txapita from the whole project if I can. It seems a lot of the code in the repository needs that package but I can't find the source package.

I've tried changing the versions to the versions in the error message
Here is my pubspec with things I've tried:

If I change the name to the name of the app it adds more errors to the output terminal when I save, is that how I get rid of the packages from the code?

```yaml
name: txapita 
description: A new Flutter application.

version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.2.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  ## I've tried doing this with the version numbers
  cloud_firestore: ">=0.11.0 <0.14.0+1"

  cupertino_icons: null
  firebase_auth: null
  firebase_core: ^2.4.1
  firebase_messaging: ^14.2.1
  flutter_google_places: null
  flutter_spinkit: ^4.1.2
  geocoder: null
  geoflutterfire: ^2.0.3+6
  geolocator: null
  google_maps_flutter: ^2.2.3
  google_maps_webservice: null
  http: null
  location: null
  modal_bottom_sheet: ^0.2.2
  percent_indicator: ^2.1.7+2
  provider: null
  rxdart: any
  shared_preferences: ^2.0.15
  uuid: null
  url_launcher: ^5.0.3
  get_it: ^1.0.3+2
  get: ^4.6.5
  share_plus: ^6.3.0
  google_sign_in: ^5.4.2
  path_provider: ^2.0.11
  path_provider_windows: ^2.1.3
  shared_preferences_windows: ^2.1.2
  path_provider_platform_interface: ^2.0.0
  platform: ^3.1.0

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_lints: ^2.0.1

flutter:
  uses-material-design: true
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using `null` or any find the package `version` by searching the package.

Link to PUB: https://pub.dev/

`E.g. : cloud_firestore: ^4.3.1`

Try running `flutter pub upgrade --major-versions`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).